# How to regenerate jQuery Mobile style after Ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, coding-style, jquery-mobile

I'd like to apply autogenerated jQuery Mobile style (classes jQuery Mobile applies on page loading) after additionnal content loading via Ajax.

I load some content via Ajax which is parsed and organised into a `<ul>`, but the style jQuery usually applies on page loading isn't applied again on the Ajax loaded content.

Comment: FYI: On listview the refresh 'method' explained by Cyril is working fine. If you are using elements which don't support 'refresh', you can use the new trigger function from 1.0b3: `$('#my_element_id').trigger('create');`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your ul is a jquery-mobile "listview", try to refresh the entire list by using :

```
$('#yourlist').listview('refresh');
```

jQuery Mobile doucmentation
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/forms/plugin-eventsmethods.html

Comment: That Good, but it seem that custom styling applied to the list seem to just disappear after the 'refresh' command is there a better way to achieve the same without loosing the custom styling applied to "list style"

Comment: I think this is deprecated now.

Comment: @ Brice Favre I'm currently trying this now but it doesn't work whatsoever. The method doesn't show in my code hints and actually causes a run-time error. It most certainly looks like it has been. Do you know of a workaround to refresh a list since this no longer works?

Answer (score 2):

I was having troubles with this refresh method as well, got it working after a bit more searching by removing 'refresh', ie :

```
$('#yourlist').listview();
```

Found with explanation at http://forum.jquery.com/topic/wish-listview-refresh-would-go-away. Works ok in 1.1.1